# how to split file on every new line in python

Tags: python

I have a txt file  to which i want to split on the basis of new line. i write code then find error in it and help me. code is

```
 file = open("C:/Python26/trigram.txt");
 f = open("Prefix.txt",'w');
 f_up = open("Prefix.txt",'w');
 contents=file.read();
 tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(contents);
 for t in tokens:
     print t
```

**my file looks like this:**

```
IL-2$gene$expression$and
IL-2$gene$expression$and$NF-kappa
IL-2$gene$expression$and$NF-kappa$B
IL-2$gene$expression$and$NF-kappa$B$activation
gene$expression$and$NF-kappa$B$activation$through
expression$and$NF-kappa$B$activation$through$CD28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
with open("C:/Python26/trigram.txt") as f:
    my_list = f.readlines()
    for x in my_list:
        print x
```

OR

```
with open("C:/Python26/trigram.txt") as f:
    for lines in f:
        print lines
```

Comment: @ShaheenGul dont edit the post when it answered, else now my answer is wrong for ur edit, you can start a new post